# How to test TaskEither form fp-ts with jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs, fp-ts

I am new to fp-ts. Let's say I have a  function `(path: string) => TaskEither<Erorr, T>` which reads and parses config, and I want to write a test for that.

So far I have:

```js
test('Read config', done => {
  interface Config {
    fld1: string
    fld2: {
      fld: 3
    }
  }

  pipe(
    readConfig<Config>("resources/test-config.toml"),
    TE.fold(
      err => T.of(done(err)),
      toml => T.of(() => {
        expect(toml).toBe({})
        done()
      })
    )
  )

})
```

But it fails due to timeout. And also I am unsure if I implemented fold correctly. How do fold `TaskEither` to `Task` in general and then call it asynchronously?

Comment: A `Task` (or a `TaskEither`) is lazy, you have to execute it to get the corresponding value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing function call.

It should have been:

```js
  pipe(
    readConfig<Config>("resources/test-config.toml"),
    TE.fold(
      err => T.of(done(err)),
      toml => T.of(() => {
        expect(toml).toBe({})
        done()
      })
    )
  )()
```

Comment: A bit late for this, but in the case someone come across, I think the _right_ part of the `fold` prevents also the whole pipe to be run (hence get a timeout), as you are returning `Task<() => void>` and the function in the _task_ is not run, opposite to  what it's returned in the _left_ (error) part of the fold: a `Task<any>` is returned and so the pipe is run when we call it.

Answer (score 1):

This post was the only I found when I was looking how to test TaskEither with jest, so here is my answer:

```
import * as TE from "fp-ts/lib/TaskEither";
import * as E from "fp-ts/lib/Either";

it("tests TaskEither", async () => {
  const fn = TE.right("something");
  await expect(fn()).resolves.toStrictEqual(E.right("something"));
})
```